# AWS Cloud Formation template to create an Image of an EC2 Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to create an AMI to Image on an EC2 instance from a Cloud Formation Template?

I have searched for all the resource types for AWS Cloud Formation but couldn't find one for AMI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create AMI image as part of a cloudformation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431450/create-ami-image-as-part-of-a-cloudformation-stack)

Answer (score 1):

**No it is not possible.**

Technical Speaking Bundling Image is a process and Not a resource

Creation of AMI would be achieved by a process called as AMI Bundling [[ec2-bundle-image]](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-bundle-image.html). Apparently using CloudFormation you can set up the infra ( AWS Components and align them in to a VPC etc.)

Below list of the EC2 based resources you do with CloudFormation.

- AWS::EC2::CustomerGateway
- AWS::EC2::DHCPOptions
- AWS::EC2::EIP
- AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation
- AWS::EC2::Instance
- AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
- AWS::EC2::NetworkAcl
- AWS::EC2::NetworkAclEntry
- AWS::EC2::NetworkInterface
- AWS::EC2::NetworkInterfaceAttachment
- AWS::EC2::Route
- AWS::EC2::RouteTable
- AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
- AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
- AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
- AWS::EC2::Subnet
- AWS::EC2::SubnetNetworkAclAssociation
- AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
- AWS::EC2::Volume
- AWS::EC2::VolumeAttachment
- AWS::EC2::VPC
- AWS::EC2::VPCDHCPOptionsAssociation
- AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
- AWS::EC2::VPNConnection
- AWS::EC2::VPNConnectionRoute
- AWS::EC2::VPNGateway