# create image of an ec2 instance using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have written the cloud formation yaml code to create a VPC with 2 public subnet in multi AZ and 2 private subnet with multi AZ. I have created internet gateway, route table & Security Group ( one for public and one for private for both RT and SG ). Associated the subnets in the respective route tables. I have created ALB and ASG. All these using cloud formation.

I have specified desired instance as 2, min as 1 and max as 4 in ASG cloudformation template. In launch configuration template I have mentioned that all the instance should be launched in private subnets with multi AZ. ALB is placed in public subnet and it is internet facing. I haven't created NAT Gateway.

I will create an instance in public subnet with the user data to install httpd. **My Question is: Is there any way to create an image of this instance. Condition in the same code**

If this is possible what I will do is I will use this ami id of the image which was created from public instance to create an instance in private subnets.

```
Resources:
  CFVPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Cloud_Formation_VPC
  CFIGW:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Cloud_Formation_IGW
  AttachGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref CFIGW
  CFPublicSubnet1a:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
        AvailabilityZone: ap-south-1a
        CidrBlock: 10.0.1.0/24
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
        Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: Public Subnet 1a
  CFPrivateSubnet1a:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
        AvailabilityZone: ap-south-1a
        CidrBlock: 10.0.2.0/24
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
        Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: Private Subnet 1a
  CFPublicSubnet1b:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
        AvailabilityZone: ap-south-1b
        CidrBlock: 10.0.3.0/24
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
        Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: Public Subnet 1b
  CFPrivateSubnet1b:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
        VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
        AvailabilityZone: ap-south-1b
        CidrBlock: 10.0.4.0/24
        MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
        Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: Private Subnet 1b
  CFPublicRT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Public RT
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
  CFPrivateRT:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Private RT
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
  routetablepublicsubnetassociation1a:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref CFPublicRT
        SubnetId: !Ref CFPublicSubnet1a
  routetablepublicsubnetassociation1b:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:
        RouteTableId: !Ref CFPublicRT
        SubnetId: !Ref CFPublicSubnet1b
  routetableprivatesubnetassociation1a:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref CFPrivateRT
      SubnetId: !Ref CFPrivateSubnet1a
  routetableprivatesubnetassociation1b:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref CFPrivateRT
      SubnetId: !Ref CFPrivateSubnet1b
  CFPublicRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref CFIGW
      RouteTableId: !Ref CFPublicRT
  CFALBSG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http/https/ssh
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 443
        ToPort: 443
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 106.51.140.198/32
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 122.179.31.197/32
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        IpProtocol: -1
  CFec2SG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow SSH
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref CFALBSG
  CFAlbTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckIntervalSeconds: 10
      HealthCheckPath: /http
      HealthCheckPort: 80
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      HealthCheckTimeoutSeconds: 7
      HealthyThresholdCount: 5
      Name: alb-target-group
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: Alb-TargetGp
      UnhealthyThresholdCount: 10
      VpcId: !Ref CFVPC
  CFALB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      IpAddressType: ipv4
      Type: application
      Name: cf-elb
      Scheme: internet-facing
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref CFALBSG
      Subnets:
        - !Ref CFPublicSubnet1a
        - !Ref CFPublicSubnet1b
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: CF-ALB
  CFALBListner:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - TargetGroupArn: !Ref CFAlbTargetGroup
          Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref CFALB
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
  CFASGLaunchConfig:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: true
      ImageId: ami-043f9106e7f451340
      InstanceMonitoring: false
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: QuadraKeyBLR
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref CFec2SG
  CFPlacementGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::PlacementGroup
    Properties:
      Strategy: spread
  CFASG:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
    Properties:
      AutoScalingGroupName: Cloudformation_autoscalling
      AvailabilityZones:
        - ap-south-1a
        - ap-south-1b
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref CFASGLaunchConfig
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref CFPrivateSubnet1a
        - !Ref CFPrivateSubnet1b
      Cooldown: 120
      DesiredCapacity: 2
      MaxSize: 4
      MinSize: 1
      PlacementGroup: !Ref CFPlacementGroup
      TargetGroupARNs:
        - !Ref CFAlbTargetGroup
```

Comment: https://medium.com/poka-techblog/managing-amis-using-cloudformation-a097f86a3622. One suggestion from my side would be to use IaaC tools like terraform if possible in your existing tool set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this question was answered already: [Create AMI image as part of a cloudformation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431450/create-ami-image-as-part-of-a-cloudformation-stack)

It's and old answer, but it still seems valid.

Thanks!